# Mongoose giving me undefined error

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

OK i don't get this one bit. it was actually working just fine a while ago but now i'm getting the following error:

**ERROR**

```
azura@AzuraMain:~$ nodejs /home/azura/Desktop/dbWrite.js
Connection to database has been established
Server is up

/home/azura/Desktop/dbWrite.js:94
    res.send("<h1>Hello</h1> " + id + " " + data.name);
                                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at /home/azura/Desktop/dbWrite.js:94:53
at /home/azura/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:160:11
at Query._findOne (/home/azura/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1145:12)
at /home/azura/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:156:8
at /home/azura/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:18:7
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I dont understand why i would be getting this error.

Here's my code:

**SERVER CODE**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(http);
//Use These Modules



app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");

});
//Create the homepage of the server



mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/NEW_DB1");
console.log("Connection to database has been established");
//Connect to the database



var collectedData = new mongoose.Schema({
    ipAddress: String,
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: false
    }
});
var collectionOfData = mongoose.model("dataType", collectedData);
//Create the mongoose schema

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
//Check for connection with socket.io



    socket.on("name", function (e) {
    //Check for "name" with socket.io



        var ip = socket.request.socket.remoteAddress;
        //Check the ip address of user



        var dataBase = mongoose.connection;
        var Maindata = new collectionOfData({
            ipAddress: ip,
            name: e
        });
        //Create the Schema with the requested name and ip



        Maindata.save(function (err, Maindata) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.dir(Maindata);

            }
        });
        //Save this into the database




    });
});




app.get("/mix", function (req, res) {
    collectionOfData.find(function (err, data) {
        res.send(data);
    });
});
//Just a test directory /mix

app.get("/:uniqueURL", function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.uniqueURL;
//Create a unique URL

    collectionOfData.findOne({
        _id: id

    }, function (err, data) {
        res.send("<h1>Hello</h1> " + id + " " + data.name);
        //This is where the issue derives from data.name is undefined? I Defined it up there and it seems to work for a second until the server crashed because of it

    });
    //Send the data to the requested page
});


http.listen(10203, function () {
    console.log("Server is up");
});
//Create the HTTP Server
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<html>

    <body>
        <form id="chooseName">
            <input class="center-block" id="name" placeholder="Post whatever the fuck you want" />
        </form>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js">
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js">  </script>
        <script>
            var socket = io();

            $("#chooseName").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit("name", $("#name").val());
                document.write("cool go to http://173.78.185.247:10203/mix to see what you have contributed to");
    });
    //Send data to the server where it gets read with socket.on("name", Do Something
        </script>
     </body>
  </html>
```

why does this happen? all i want is to make data.name print out the requested name of the user. it seems to work for a second but then the server just crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is no matching document in collection data then findOne() can provide null in data object.

debug by printing id, err, and data.

Comment: Nvm just read it wrong. ok ill get back to you if it won't work after the debug

Comment: Debug doesn't seem to print anything useful. at least i don't understand it. what im confused about is why am i getting this error now, when it wasn't happening literally an hour ago

Comment: as per your error, data is undefined. So id must be wrong or not in db

Comment: Im honestly so confused, I started working with database a couple days ago, and all these errors happening to me are driving me crazy.

Comment: but data is defined? it actually prints out what i need before the server crashes

Comment: I used your advice, i just moved my app.get("/:uniqueURL", doSomething); to a place where data was already defined / had a variable of it

Comment: you have defined variable data, but based on findOne response, if there is no matching document ("_id" :  id) in your collection, then findOne returns the data as null. and if you try to access null object's name property. that will throw the error;